# If $\frac{1}{f}$ is unbounded around $x=3$, then $\lim_{x\to\ 3}f = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is the following true? If $\frac{1}{f}$ is unbounded in every interval containing $x=3$, then $\lim_{x\to\ 3}f = 0$.

I know this is false since I have seen a counter example. However, I couldn't figure out the flaw in my "proof".

For any $M>0$ and for any $\delta>0$, $x\in (3-\delta,3+\delta)$ implies that $\bigl| \frac{1}{f}\bigr|>M$, which is equivalent to say that $x\in (3-\delta,3+\delta)$ implies $\frac{1}{M}>|f|$. Let $\epsilon= \frac{1}{M}$. Thus, by taking very big $M$ and very small $\delta$, we can show that $x\in(3-\delta,3+\delta)$ implies $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$

Comment: What is your counterexample? I think your problem is with the confusion of being "unbounded" and "having infinity as limit".  You proof operates with the assumption that $\lim_{x \to 3} 1/f = \infty$.

Comment: Thta's $\exists x\in (3-\delta,3+\delta)$. It's not for *all* $x$ in that interval, which would be required to show $f \to 0$.

Comment: You could have something like $\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-3}\right)}{(x-3)^2}$ that both grows and oscillates.

Comment: Simply, the unbounded-ness of $\frac{1}{f}$ is a neighbourhood of $x=3$ does not imply that $\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)$ *exists*.

Comment: Take $f(x)=x-3$ if $x$ is an irrational number, and $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is a rational number, for instance.